# Should a Software project have a Detailed Design phase that describes the code?

Tags: design

Should a Software project have a Detailed Design phase, in which the detailed specifications (ie, the code) are spelt out?

The reason I ask about this is that finding the right syntax to be used may be difficult, given the myriad language features available. Therefore, it might be best to design the code *before* actual coding and then review the design.

If so, what kind of medium would be good for spelling out the code?

1. If we use a WP tool (such as MS-Word), compilation errors wouldn't be caught.
2. Therefore, can we use the IDE itself as a detailed design medium?
3. If we use a graphical tool (such as a UML tool), again it wouldn't be at the code level and compilation errors wouldn't be caught.

The [following post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58086/design-code-outside-of-an-ide) suggests using the IDE.

Please note that I am *not* asking for advice about any specific tool. The query is only about the approach that should be followed for doing detailed design of the code, *prior to* actual coding.

Comment: Are you asking about pseudo-coding (like individual functions or methods) or doing a class design?

Comment: @Becuzz, No; I am not asking about pseudo-coding. I was asking about designing the actual code, prior to actual coding.

Comment: You obviously misunderstood that linked question - it does not suggest to use the IDE (for "design before coding"), it suggests to use a whiteboard. The suggestion to use the IDE means clearly: after you scetched your design at a whiteboard, start coding.

Comment: @SSteven Then I am really lost.  You talk about designing the code before coding using something like an IDE.  If you are thinking an IDE would be an appropriate tool, that suggests writing code of some kind (possibly pseudo code).  If that's not what you mean, what do you mean by "designing the code before coding"?  Like designing interfaces and class interactions?  Deciding what responsibilities belong to which entity?  Designing subsystems or modules?  Overarching design principles for your application?  An example might be helpful in understanding what you are getting at here.

Comment: @Becuzz, the point you have raised is valid. I shall answer it by editing my original post, to clarify what I meant. Right now, I am reading the external links that had been posted in the replies, so please bear with me till then.

Comment: You are renaming the "coding" stage to "design" and then asking whether you should code in MS Word.

Answer (score 6):

You're confused about the difference between detailed design and coding.

From a comment you posted:

> during the detailed design. The way I see it, the Design phase would comprise 2 stages : High-level and Detailed. While "High-level" would identify the data structures and list of programs, Detailed design would spell out the logic. If the logic is stated only in words, it leaves risk at the coding level - can the logic be accurately translated into code in a timely manner? Therefore, it would be a risk-mitigation device to design the code as well.

As of 2018, skilled humans are still required to create useful software. Don't let all the machine learning hype fool you, human skill, not process, is still the most important link in the chain.

> If the logic is stated only in words, it leaves risk at the coding level - can the logic be accurately translated into code in a timely manner?

Turning logic described with natural language into logical instructions a machine can perform, is **the fundamental skill** of software developers. That process has to be done somewhere.  That risk is going to be present, as long as us humans are in the process. You think you are mitigating the risk, but you are just moving it and making it more expensive.

What you are describing here, is turning "coders" into typists. Doing so is not going to bring you any benefit, but it will bring you substantial cost. You've already realized some of the trouble you are inviting to yourself. You could write an entire software program in MS Word, then hand it off to someone else to brainlessly copy into an IDE. But like you are concerned about, MS word doesn't do any compilation checks. None of the tooling is there. And what's the likelyhood you can write a multi-thousand line program, and have it work flawlessly on the very first test? Pretty unlikely. Now your typist has to go back to you and you have to edit your MS word document, and try again over and over, with a huge hassle and cost each time. You've realized the risk of coders taking too long to write the code, turning it into the reality of someone else writing the code, using a really god-awful development environment, and took just as much or longer to accomplish nothing.

At some point you realize, since the person writing the Word doc is the only one you trust with **the fundamental skill** to do the actual programming, maybe that person should just be the one to type everything into the IDE in the first place.

Natural spoken languages are very poor language for communication of super-precise subject matters. Spoken languages are incredibly context sensitive. Programming languages do not. A detailed design is written ideally in the sweet spot between natural language and technical language, with the point on that spectrum varying based on skill of the developers and the risk of the project.

Comment: `What you are describing here, is turning "coders" into typists.` - There were (are?) some attempts to do this. Some organizations have attempted to fully specify a software project - have the engineers produce detailed specifications, models, diagrams, pictures, tables, etc. and then hand them off to coders. This doesn't work because the act of coding is not construction. Coding is just as much of a design activity as making diagrams. I think the last two paragraphs (especially) hit the points very well.

Comment: @whatsisname, I wasn’t suggesting using AI / machine learning to do coding, or turning coders into typists, or using MS-Word as a tool to enter the code. Of course, the IDE would be a much better place to enter the code, because of intelligent prompting, error-checking, etc. In fact, my original post (as you point out) was oriented toward the IDE.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: That's an apt description of the problems that occur with offshoring.  To make offshoring succeed, you pretty much have to fully specify a software project, and by the time you do that, you might as well have written the software yourself.

Comment: @SSteven: I think you're missing the point.

Comment: Agreed. We have a name for that: Software Factories. Curiously, it's an attempt to cut down production costs, but as commented here, It just make everything harder to take forward and hence, expensive

Answer (score 5):

The most detailed design of a software system is the code (see [these essays by Jack W. Reeves](https://www.developerdotstar.com/mag/articles/reeves_design_main.html) or [this C2 Wiki article/discussion](http://wiki.c2.com/?TheSourceCodeIsTheDesign)). In order to actually build any kind of useful software, you must do detailed design. You then must take the output of this detailed design (the code) and turn it into a useful software product (by compiling or interpreting it).

It does not make sense to write code in anything other than an IDE or editor of some kind. There's a broad spectrum of good tools for writing code, depending on your platform, language, and personal preferences.

A good question would then be how much design is necessary before writing code. And that depends a lot on your platform. That depends on what the system is and does. I would expect that a mobile app for a card game would have a different level of design put into it than the embedded software for a pacemaker or a business application that a large multi-national corporation depends on to do their work.

I would expect that any pre-code design work would take plain-language text, tabular data, or graphical data. In some very rigorous environments, perhaps [formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods) would be used. But I would expect that none of these would focus on the details of the programming language or platform - these details would arise when doing "detailed design" (or coding). I would not expect your pre-code design work to be devoid of all knowledge of the programming language. I consider decisions like infrastructure, operating systems, programming language, and frameworks to be architectural decisions that would put constraints on any more detailed design that was required based on the nature of the project.

Comment: I get the gist. What is being suggested is: After the Design, move on to code. Do coding in the IDE. Then, the code can be reviewed.

Comment: @SSteven: That seems self-evident.  But it also seems like a different idea than the one you posed in your original question.

Comment: @SSteven More important than being reviewed is being built and tested. It is (relatively, compared to other types of systems and products) very cheap to build and test software components, in terms of resources but also time and cost. What you propose in your question is very costly with very little benefit.

Comment: @SSteven: to me it sounds more like you  misunderstood this. Any coding (in the IDE) **is** part of the design. There is surely some part of the design, especially high level design, happening before coding, but nothing like "coding after the design".

Comment: @Robert, by “different idea” did you mean (a) Moving on to Code after Design? I was summarizing the gist of the replies. Or did you mean (b) Reviews?

Comment: @Thomas, Reviews are cheaper and more effective than Testing. In increasing order of formality Code Review techniques are: Reviews, Walkthroughs and Inspections. The following data is from “Estimating S/W Costs”, T Capers Jones, 2nd Ed - (DRE = Defect Removal Efficiency) Inspections: avg DRE = 65%; best results exceed 85%. Walkthroughs: avg DRE =  45%; best: > 70%. Reviews (using Agile “Pair-Programming”), avg DRE = 50%; best > 75%. Most forms of Testing: DRE is < 30%. Steve McConnell also emphasizes the importance of Reviews vs Testing (S/W Project Survival Guide,  1998, Ch 9 (QA).

Comment: @SSteven I'm not suggesting that you shouldn't review. However, if you need to be able to build (compile or execute via an interpreter) your software for it to be useful - having something that builds is very important to customers and users. Tests are also fast and repeatable, ensuring that what you are reviewing is functional. Why waste time reviewing code that doesn't work? You can also review the tests with an eye toward building a set of regression and smoke tests that are useful when doing something like upgrading dependencies where a review may not catch a change in underlying behavior.

Comment: In Jack Reeves’ articles on “Source Code is the Design”, I found the answer I was looking for. Reeves’ articles were very insightful. As he states, the only artifact that fully meets the criteria of a design document, is the source code, since it alone can be turned over to manufacturing, to get the product (which, according to him, is the executable). Therefore, the Source Code is the (final) design document. Where else would one design the source code, but in the IDE?

Answer (score 1):

> Should a Software project have a Detailed Design phase ... ?

Of course.

Having a plan is always better than not having a plan. Whether you actually do that or not (and to what degree you do that) depends on many factors, such as time constraints, complexity of the software, the level of rigor required, and so forth.

> ... in which the detailed specifications (ie, the code) are spelt out?  Finding the right syntax to be used may be difficult, given the myriad language features available.

Thinking about syntax before you even know what you are building is premature.

Your job as a software developer is to convert the requirements and specifications you receive into code that satisfies those requirements and specifications.  The stakeholders that provide you with these instructions are not concerned in the least what language features or syntax you use; it is your job to figure that out.

> Therefore, it might be best to design the code before actual coding and then review the design.

If by that, you mean knock up a class hierarchy and a reasonably good architectural structure, sure.  If you mean choosing data structures having the proper performance characteristics, of course.  Language features will play some part in that, because you need classes in your language for a class diagram to make sense.  Your design approach is going to be very different if your language choice is, say, Lisp or Haskell instead of C# or Java.

But at that point you're no longer gathering requirements from business analysts.  Instead, you're getting together with your team leader or technical manager to work out a design or (depending on the size of the company) designing the software yourself.

Comment: 1) @Robert, I was asking about the detailed design phase, The SDLC I am assuming is Requirements - Analysis - Design (High-level and then Detailed) - Coding - Testing. So at this stage, we would be clear about what we are building.  (2) While it is true that the end-users wouldn't be interested in the language features to be used, the Software company would be (or should be) interested; especially in risk-mitigation, algorithmic efficiency, quality, understandability, etc.

Comment: I've modified my answer to address your concerns.

Comment: during the _detailed_ design. The way I see it, the Design phase would comprise 2 stages : High-level and Detailed. While "High-level" would identify the data structures and list of programs, Detailed design would spell out the logic. If the logic is stated only in words, it leaves risk at the coding level - can the logic be accurately translated into code in a timely manner? Therefore, it would be a risk-mitigation device to design the code as well.

Comment: See my update and respond in a comment.  I have the feeling that you think you can design every element of the code before you write it.  The code *is* the design; generally you design code by writing it.

Answer (score 1):

**It's not in line with modern development lifecylces**

The detailed design is used in a waterfall approach with a predefined phase model such as plan, analyse, general design, detailed design, implementation, test and acceptance.

This approach is outdated. Modern software development approaches are agile, with iterative cycles in which detailed design is made together with the implementation, because they are both completely interlinked.

**Detailed design documentation is quickly outdated**

Regardless of the development lifecycle, once the code is started being produced, there will be lot's of adjustment in the design, because of unexpected interrelations, change in the requirements, or simply great ideas of improvement.

Very quickly detailed design documents will be out of sync.  This will not only cost additional efforts to update, but it will also make the documentation useless:  whenever some question arises about the detailed design, people will wonder if it's up to date and check in the code.

**Can the code be its own documentation ?**

Booch's early recommendation was to document in the design, things that can not easily be understood from the code, such as the overall structure of the components, relationships between classes, complex interactions between objects, and so on. You could also document the rationale for some important design decisions.  But let the code document the details (either in self explanatory code or in some additional comments).

Answer (score 0):

> Should a Software project have a Detailed Design phase ... ?

No!

Making a plan take a lot of time and often with software project you will find that the requirements change while you are planning or developing the software. Making your plan useless.

For most software projects an Agile Methodology, where you don't do detailed planning but just straight into developing features can achieve better results.

Or at least warn you when your project is failing before you incur a large cost.

> ..what kind of medium would be good for spelling out the code?

User stories and rough sketches, just enough to communicate a small feature

[image]

Comment: "Working iteratively" and "Working without a plan" are not the same thing.  You can still  stand up rapid prototypes within the context of an overall plan, and that's a very good thing to do.  There are some things you just can't wing.  For example, how do you intend to communicate between machines?  JSON?  Something else?  You can't reliably build anything without making some basic decisions first.

Comment: Hold up. Not every software is online todo lists and social media sites. Writing software for a pacemaker or an industrial machine definitely needs plans and can't be sensibly built one feature at a time.

Comment: @whatsisname Just because you develop one feature at a time doesn't mean you have to deploy one feature at a time, though even there it easy to imagine additional features that can be deployed later to an industrial machine and [apparently pacemakers too](https://www.fda.gov/MedicalDevices/Safety/AlertsandNotices/ucm573669.htm). That said, I do agree with Robert Harvey that working iteratively is not incompatible with having a plan.

Comment: lets not forget the that the OP is asking about a "detailed design _phase_"

Answer (score 0):

From my experience that would be too much. Planning should focus on business value. Features so to speak.
Then quality criteria about those features.
Maybe certain technical aspects if they are somehow fixed.
But the "how" it is implemented is coming later.
In my experience describing the business value well enough so that it can be developed, tested and successfully delivered is the greatest concern.
Leave the implementation to the developers.

In scrum the implementation specific planning is done in the task breakdown by the team short before implementation. That way you make sure the detailed planning is not out dated.

Maybe have code reviews and coding dojos so that all developers are up to date with what your language and framework has to offer.

The more detailed you plan, the higher the risk the plan is wrong. And if you have a precious plan that you worked so hard on, it can be mentally difficult to change it. But you must! Plans never work as expected, especially the big ones. (Exaggerating a bit maybe. Some plans work, but mostly short term)

Don't get me wrong, you should plan!
And a more detailed plan is better than a too simple one, as long as you stay agile and are ok with adapting your plan.
However, adapting your plan is effort too!

I guess everyone can see I'm into agile / scrum and XP...

I've experienced many pointless planning meanings. We missed deadlines, and the mistake we made was that we thought we had to plan better and better and more detailed. The "better" we planned the more the plan was off...

Continuous planning is what helped us here.

Enough rambling, I hope I could help